# regex for 1st letter capital, allow spaces and allow one special character

Tags: javascript

i need to check for a string that should start with capital letters, should allow space and should allow &(special character)
it should not accept:

1. Numbers
2. special characters except &
3. and it should not end with &

For eg this will be accepted:  `XILJIH OIIO& IHH`

For eg this will be not accepted: `XILJIH OIIO& IHH&`

Comment: what you try for this share

Comment: You can build any kind of regex here http://regex101.com, you will get code also

Comment: what should it not allow? Also share some sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: we can check in chrome itself.@AbhijitJagtap

Comment: here is it ^[A-Z]+(\w*|\s*|\&)*$ https://regex101.com/r/oUxzbU/1

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón not working

Comment: look at the link of demo, ??, give a string for test, please

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón eg: Nandini & Nandini and if i put Nandini &   xyxxyxy it should not accept

Comment: Nandini & Nandini, WORKS in my demo here is again with your text https://regex101.com/r/oUxzbU/2/

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón var b = new RegExp("^[A-Z]+(\w*|\s*|\&)*$") b.test("Nandn & dfghjka") saying false in Chrome

Comment: read the doc of Regex because it works, but your not using well, here is a fille https://jsfiddle.net/vo6La276/ and try only to do this console.log(/^[A-Z]+(\w*|\s*|\&)*$/.test("Nandn & dfghjka")), its what you need

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón it is acceptng & at the end also..

Comment: please review your question put a fiddle, a demo text and explicit exactly what you want, i didnt understund what you need

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón  https://jsfiddle.net/vo6La276/ string should not end with "&"  but given fiddle link accepting & at the end

Comment: I suggest you to 1 make the regex, and then by js ask if last letter is not  a "&"

Answer (score 2):

Here you are

```
^[A-Z][A-Za-z &]*$
```

or what Álvaro Touzón suggested in the comment

Answer (score 0):

^[A-Z]([ ]?[&A-Za-z]+)*[^&][a-zA-Z]*$